# SQL Server: joining from multiple tables with unique data

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, unique

I have 3 tables like this.

**Table1**:

```
ID  ClaimNo Data1
1   1   EC11
2   1   EC12
4   2   EC21
```

**Table2**:

```
ID  ClaimNo Data2
1   1   IWC11
3   2   IWC21
4   2   IWC22
5   2   IWC23
```

**Table3**:

```
ID  ClaimNo Data3
1   1   DC11
2   1   DC12
3   1   DC13
4   1   DC14
5   1   DC15
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
ClaimNo Data1   Data2   Data3
------------------------------
   1    EC11    IWC11   DC11
   1    EC12            DC12
   1                    DC13
   1                    DC14    
   1                    DC15
   2    EC21    IWC21   
   2            IWC22   
   2            IWC23
```

Can any one please help me with query statement.

Comment: format your sample data and desired output they're unclear

Comment: @Farhęg: Thank you for your feedbacks and sorry for bad format. Is it better now?

Comment: you are welcome, yes it's better, just let me to review it.

Comment: you forgot to tag your RDBMS

Comment: @Farhęg: I'm using SQL server 2008 R2. Regards.

Comment: great so add the tags to question.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to organize the data in columns.  The problem is that the table have no key for joining on.  Fortunately, `row_number()` offers a solution -- you can generate a sequence number for joining.

Then, the join that you want is `full outer join` -- because you don't know which table will have the longest list.  There is a bit of extra logic, using `coalesce()`, to be sure that rows in `table3` match on of the previous two tables:

```
select coalesce(t1.claimno, t2.claimno, t3.claimno) as claimno,
       t1.data as data1, t2.data as data2, t3.data as data3
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by claimno order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by claimno order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 t2
     ) t2 full outer join
     on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum and t1.claimno = t2.claimno
     (select t3.*, row_number() over (partition by claimno order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 t3
     ) t3
     on t3.claimno = coalesce(t1.claimno, t2.claimno) and
        t3.seqnum = coalesce(t1.seqnum, t2.seqnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your all support. It seems we dont have direct answer. I think I can run below query for temp data

```html
select T1.ClaimNo, 
    T1.Data1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data1 ORDER BY Data1) AS Data1Rk, 
    T2.Data2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data2 ORDER BY Data2) AS Data2Rk,
    T3.Data3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data3 ORDER BY Data3) AS Data3Rk
from (Table1 T1 left join Table2 T2 on T1.ClaimNo=T2.ClaimNo) left join Table3 T3 on T1.ClaimNo=T3.ClaimNo
```

Here is result set

```html
ClaimNo Data1 Data1Rk Data2 Data2Rk Data3 Data2Rk
2 EC21 1 IWC21 1 NULL 1
2 EC21 2 IWC22 1 NULL 2
2 EC21 3 IWC23 1 NULL 3
1 EC11 1 IWC11 1 DC11 1
1 EC12 1 IWC11 6 DC11 2
1 EC12 2 IWC11 7 DC12 1
1 EC11 2 IWC11 2 DC12 2
1 EC11 3 IWC11 3 DC13 1
1 EC12 3 IWC11 8 DC13 2
1 EC12 4 IWC11 9 DC14 1
1 EC11 4 IWC11 4 DC14 2
1 EC11 5 IWC11 5 DC15 1
1 EC12 5 IWC11 10 DC15 2
```

then I do filtering the result by rk=1 and not null data